# Regular expression for select unknown text in the line

Tags: python, regex

I have a following strings:

```
static name p1SystemSignalAlarm_oid = {4.3.4.2.1}
static name p1SystemKfLinkNet_oid = {3.4.1.5.7}
```

I need to get "Alarm" from first line and "Net" from second line.
I succeeded select SystemSignalAlarm_oid and I can select words that are needed by using strip. But it would be great if I can use one regular expression. How can I should select it?

Comment: You just want the word alarm, or net? or you want the value on the otherside of the assignment?

Comment: I tried line = static name p1SystemSignalAlarm_oid = {4.3.4.2.1}
result = re.search(r'\BSignal\B'w+', line)

Comment: I need a value before "_oid" But not all text before "_oid"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will find either `Alarm` or `Net` from your sample lines:

```
for item in lines:
    result = re.findall(r'([A-Z][a-z]+)_oid', item)
    print result[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need the word between the last uppercase and the underscore. So:

```
([A-Z][a-z]*)_
```

And then take group number 1, to ignore the underscore:

```
>>> re.search('([A-Z][a-z]*)_', 'p1SystemSignalAlarm_oid').group(1)
'Alarm'
>>> re.search('([A-Z][a-z]*)_', 'p1SystemKfLinkNet_oid).group(1)
'Net'
```